# JAVA ¿Imprimir una parte de los atributos de un objeto por pantalla?

Tags: java

Necesito ayuda con el siguiente código

El programa en si es una aplicación que se presentaría por la consola solamente. Se debe permitir el ingreso, consulta, modificaron y eliminación de estudiantes, profesores, secretarios, conserjes y calificaciones.

Se debe ingresar como un tipo de usuario y cada tipo de usuario tiene ciertas limitaciones:

En este caso estamos desarrollando el apartado del administrador, el cual puede hacer todo. Todo se da con normalidad, el problema surge al momento de ingresar y mostrar los datos de los profesores, pues el atributo de materias que tienen, tanto la clase "Profesor" como Estudiante, parte de la clase "materia", la cual tiene como uno de sus atributos las "Calificaciones", en los estudiantes esta bien que se muestren las calificaciones, pero en los profesores no deberían mostrarse, pues los profesores no tienen calificaciones en las materias que imparten.
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
La pregunta es como hacer para que la parte de calificaciones no se muestre al momento de presentar los profesores?, realmente estoy algo perdido en este punto y no se si debería modificar o agregar algún método en alguna de esas clases o si se puede arreglar con alguna condición puesta en alguna parte.

Codigo principal:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProyectoPOO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int TipoPersona,Sistema=1,Accion,Aux,Tipo;
        
        LinkedList LE= new LinkedList();
        LinkedList LP= new LinkedList();
        LinkedList LS= new LinkedList();
        LinkedList LC= new LinkedList();
        
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su tipo de usuario:");
            System.out.println("1. Estudiante");
            System.out.println("2. Profesor");
            System.out.println("3. Secretario");
            System.out.println("4. Conserje");
            System.out.println("5. Administrador");
            System.out.println("6. Salir");
            TipoPersona=sc.nextInt();
            switch(TipoPersona){
            
            case 1: //Estudiante
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
            break;
            
            case 2: //Profesor
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
            break;
            
            case 3: //Secretario
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
            break;
            
            case 4: //Conserje
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
            break;
            
            case 5: //Administrador
                do{
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
                System.out.println("1. Modificar Estudiantes");
                System.out.println("2. Modificar Profesores");
                System.out.println("3. Modificar Secretarias");
                System.out.println("4. Modificar Conserjes");
                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                    switch(Accion){
                        case 1: //Estudiantes
                            Tipo=1;
                            do{
                                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer en el apartado de Estudiantes?");
                                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Estudiante");
                                System.out.println("2. Consultar Estudiantes");
                                System.out.println("3. Modificar Datos Estudiante");
                                System.out.println("4. Eliminar Estudiante");
                                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                                switch(Accion){
                            
                                    case 1: //Ingresar Estudiante
                                        
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LE);
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LE.size()); //Para asegurar q se guardan los objetos
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Consultar Estudiantes
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LE.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LE);
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Modificar Datos Estudiante
                                        
                                        mostrarDatos(LE);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del estudiante del cual modificara sus datos");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese nueva modificacion");
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LE);
                                        LE.set(Aux,LE.getLast());
                                        LE.removeLast();
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 4: //Eliminar Estudiante
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LE.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LE);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del Estudiante a eliminar:");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        LE.remove(Aux);
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 5: //Retroceder
                                        Sistema=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            
                            }while(Sistema==1);
                            Sistema=1;
                        break;
                        
                        case 2: //Profesores
                            Tipo=2;
                            do{
                                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer en el apartado de Profesores?");
                                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Profesores");
                                System.out.println("2. Consultar Profesores");
                                System.out.println("3. Modificar Datos Profesores");
                                System.out.println("4. Eliminar Profesores");
                                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                                switch(Accion){
                            
                                    case 1: //Ingresar profesor
                                        
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LP);
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LP.size());
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Consultar profesor
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LP.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LP);
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Modificar Datos profesor
                                        
                                        mostrarDatos(LP);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del eprofesor del cual modificara sus datos");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese nueva modificacion");
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LP);
                                        LP.set(Aux,LP.getLast());
                                        LP.removeLast();
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 4: //Eliminar profesor
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LP.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LP);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del profesor a eliminar:");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        LP.remove(Aux);
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 5: //Retroceder
                                        Sistema=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            
                            }while(Sistema==1);
                            Sistema=1;
                        break;
                        
                        case 3: //Secretarios
                            Tipo=3;
                            do{
                                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer en el apartado de Secretarios?");
                                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Secretario");
                                System.out.println("2. Consultar SecretarioS");
                                System.out.println("3. Modificar Datos Secretario");
                                System.out.println("4. Eliminar Secretario");
                                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                                switch(Accion){
                            
                                    case 1: //Ingresar Secretario
                                        
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LS);
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LS.size());
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Consultar Secretario
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LS.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LS);
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Modificar Datos Secretario
                                        
                                        mostrarDatos(LS);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del Secretario del cual modificara sus datos");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese nueva modificacion");
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LS);
                                        LS.set(Aux,LS.getLast());
                                        LS.removeLast();
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 4: //Eliminar Estudiante
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LS.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LS);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del Secretario a eliminar:");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        LS.remove(Aux);
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 5: //Retroceder
                                        Sistema=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            
                            }while(Sistema==1);
                            Sistema=1;
                        break;
                        
                        case 4: //Conserje
                            Tipo=4;
                            do{
                                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer en el apartado de ConserjeS?");
                                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Conserje");
                                System.out.println("2. Consultar Conserjes");
                                System.out.println("3. Modificar Datos Conserje");
                                System.out.println("4. Eliminar Conserje");
                                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                                switch(Accion){
                            
                                    case 1: //Ingresar Conserje
                                        
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LC);
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LC.size());
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Consultar Conserje
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LC.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LC);
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Modificar Datos Conserje
                                        
                                        mostrarDatos(LC);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del Conserje del cual modificara sus datos");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese nueva modificacion");
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LC);
                                        LC.set(Aux,LC.getLast());
                                        LC.removeLast();
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 4: //Eliminar Estudiante
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LC.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LC);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del Conserje a eliminar:");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        LC.remove(Aux);
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 5: //Retroceder
                                        Sistema=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            
                            }while(Sistema==1);
                            Sistema=1;
                        break;
                        
                        case 5: //Retroceder
                        Sistema=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }while(Sistema==1);
                Sistema=1;
            break;
            case 6: //Salir del Sistema
                Sistema=0;
            break;}
        }while(Sistema==1);

    }
```

Parte del codigo que permite el ingreso de datos:

```
public static void ingresoDatos(int Tipo,LinkedList lista)
    {
        String nombre,apellido,cedula,telefono,direccion,carrera,semestreC;
        
        String turno;
        
        int i,edad,años_servicio,año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg,cant_materias,cant_carreras;
        
        double parcial1,parcial2,recuperacion;
        
        String nombre_materia,codigo_materia, semestreM, id_carrera;
        
        Calificaciones calificaciones;
        Materia materias;
        List<Materia> materiasD= new ArrayList<Materia>();
        List<Materia> materias_semestre;
        materias_semestre = new ArrayList<Materia>();
        
        Fecha f_nacimiento;
        Fecha f_inicio;
        Fecha f_final;
        Fecha f_ingreso;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre:");
            nombre=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su apellido:");
            apellido=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su cedula:");
            cedula=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su edad:");
            edad=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            f_nacimiento= new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            System.out.println("Ingrese su telefono:");
            telefono=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su direccion:");
            direccion=sc.nextLine();
            
        
        if (Tipo == 1){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera:");
            carrera=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su semestre:");
            semestreC=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            f_inicio= new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            f_final= new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese Catidad Materias:");
            cant_materias=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            for(i=0;i<cant_materias;i++){
                System.out.println("Ingrese Nombre Materia:");
                nombre_materia=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Codigo Materia:");
                codigo_materia=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Semestre Materia:");
                semestreM=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese ID Materia:");
                id_carrera=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Calificacion Parcial 1 de la Materia "+nombre_materia);
                parcial1=sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Calificacion Parcial 2 de la Materia "+nombre_materia);
                parcial2=sc.nextDouble();
                if ((parcial1+parcial2)/2<7)
                {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese Calificacion Recuperacion de la Materia "+nombre_materia);
                    recuperacion=sc.nextDouble();
                }
                else
                {
                    recuperacion=0;
                }
                sc.nextLine();
                calificaciones = new Calificaciones(parcial1,parcial2,recuperacion);
                materias= new Materia(nombre_materia,codigo_materia,semestreM,id_carrera,calificaciones);
                materias_semestre.add(materias);
            }

            lista.add(new Estudiante(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,semestreC,f_inicio,f_final,materias_semestre));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
        
        if (Tipo == 2){
        do{
            LinkedList carreras=new LinkedList();
            System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de carreras a las que asiste:");
            cant_carreras=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            for(i=0;i<cant_carreras;++i)
            {
                System.out.println("Ingrese CARRERA "+i+":");
                carrera=sc.nextLine();
                carreras.add(carrera);
            }
            System.out.println("Ingrese Catidad Materias:");
            cant_materias=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            for(i=0;i<cant_materias;i++){
                System.out.println("Ingrese Nombre Materia:");
                nombre_materia=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Codigo Materia:");
                codigo_materia=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Semestre Materia:");
                semestreM=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese ID Materia:");
                id_carrera=sc.nextLine();
                calificaciones=new Calificaciones(0,0,0);
                materias= new Materia(nombre_materia,codigo_materia,semestreM,id_carrera,calificaciones);
                materiasD.add(materias);
            }
            
            lista.add(new Profesor(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carreras,materiasD));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
        
        if (Tipo == 3){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera:");
            carrera=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            f_ingreso=new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            System.out.println("Ingrese sus años de servicio:");
            años_servicio=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su turno (mañana o tarde):");
            turno=sc.nextLine();
            lista.add(new Secretario(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,f_ingreso,años_servicio,turno));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
        
        if (Tipo == 4){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera:");
            carrera=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            f_ingreso=new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            System.out.println("Ingrese sus años de servicio:");
            años_servicio=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su turno (mañana, tarde o noche):");
            turno=sc.nextLine();
            lista.add(new Secretario(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,f_ingreso,años_servicio,turno));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
    }
```

Parte del codigo que permite mostrar los Datos:

```
public static void mostrarDatos(LinkedList lista)
    {
        Persona p;
        for(int i=0;i<lista.size();++i)
        {
            System.out.println
        ("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            
            p=(Persona)lista.get(i);
            System.out.println(i+" - "+p.mostrar());
            
            System.out.println
        ("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
```

Clase Estudiante:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Estudiante extends Persona{
    
    protected String carrera,semestre;
    protected List<Materia> materias_semestre;
    protected Fecha f_inicio,f_final;
    
    public Estudiante(String nombre,String apellido, String cedula, int edad, Fecha f_nacimiento,String telefono,String direccion,String carrera,String semestre,Fecha f_inicio,Fecha f_final,List<Materia> materias_semestre){
        
        super(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion);
        this.carrera=carrera;
        this.semestre=semestre;
        this.f_inicio=f_inicio;
        this.f_final=f_final;
        this.materias_semestre=materias_semestre;
    }
    
    public String mostrar(){
        
        return (nombre+" "+apellido+" "+cedula+" "+edad+" "+f_nacimiento.mostrarF()+" "+telefono+" "+direccion+" "+carrera+" "+semestre+" "+f_inicio.mostrarF()+" "+f_final.mostrarF()+"\n"+materias_semestre);
    }

}
```

Clase Profesor:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Profesor extends Persona{
    
    protected List<String> carreras;
    protected List<Materia> materias;
    
    public Profesor(String nombre,String apellido, String cedula, int edad, Fecha f_nacimiento,String telefono,String direccion,List carreras,List materias){
        
        super(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion);
        this.carreras=carreras;
        this.materias=materias;
        
    }
    
    public String mostrar(){
        
        return (nombre+" "+apellido+" "+cedula+" "+edad+" "+f_nacimiento.mostrarF()+" "+telefono+" "+direccion+" "+carreras+""+materias);
    }
}
```

Clase Materia:

```
public class Materia {
    
    protected String nombre_materia,codigo_materia, semestre, id_carrera;
    protected Calificaciones calificaciones;
    
    public Materia(String nombre_materia,String codigo_materia, String semestre, String id_carrera, Calificaciones calificaciones)
    {
        this.nombre_materia=nombre_materia;
        this.codigo_materia=codigo_materia;
        this.semestre=semestre;
        this.id_carrera=id_carrera;
        this.calificaciones=calificaciones;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        
        
        return "MATERIA: "+nombre_materia+"/"+codigo_materia+"/"+semestre+"/"+id_carrera+" CALIFICACIONES-> "+calificaciones.toString()+"\n";
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Clase Calificaciones:

```
public class Calificaciones {
    
    protected double parcial1,parcial2,recuperacion;
    
    public Calificaciones(double parcial1,double parcial2,double recuperacion)
    {
        this.parcial1=parcial1;
        this.parcial2=parcial2;
        this.recuperacion=recuperacion;
        //this.nota_final=nota_final;
    }
  
    public String toString(){
        if ((parcial1+parcial2)/2>=7){
            
            return "Parcial 1: "+parcial1+"/ Parcial 2: "+parcial2+"/ Nota Final: "+((parcial1+parcial2)/2);
        }
        else{
            return "Parcial 1: "+parcial1+"/ Parcial 2: "+parcial2+"/ Recuperación: "+recuperacion+"/ Nota Final: "+((((parcial1+parcial2)/2)*0.6)+(recuperacion*0.4));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Me parece un poco raro como has diseñado las clases. Una calificación es algo propio de un alumno, no algo propio de una materia. Me parecería más lógico que un alumno tuviese calificaciones de las materias en las que está matriculado. Esto lo podrías hacer de varias maneras, por ejemplo teniendo un Map<Materia, Calificaciones> o teniendo una lista de Calificaciones, y que cada calificación estuviese relacionado con una materia, etc.